# Missing int values when importing from csv into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

I'm currently building a database that works with helping students build a class schedule. I've "succeeded" in importing two of the three columns using a csv file but I'm having issues importing the ID numbers for the fields the classes are apart of. I think it has something to do with the ID being a int file, since the other two columns are varchar's. But having the column be int makes the rest of my project incredibly easy...

A small portion of the csv file reads:

```
1,AFAM,2000
1,AFAM,3150
1,PSYC,3150
1,AFAM,3880
1,AFAM,4200
2,POLS,4200
2,AFAM,4490
2,AFAM,6490
2,DRAM,4490
2,DRAM,6490
2,AFAM,4500
```

Then I use this in MySQL:

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'Course_Requirements.csv' INTO TABLE Courses
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

When I go `SELECT * FROM COURSES;` to view my table it shows up like this:

```
ID  |  ClassName  |  ClassNumber
    |  AFAM       |  2000
    |  AFAM       |  3150
    |  PSYC       |  3150
    |  AFAM       |  3880
    |  AFAM       |  4200
    |  POLS       |  4200
    |  AFAM       |  4490
    |  AFAM       |  6490
    |  DRAM       |  4490
    |  DRAM       |  6490
 2  |  AFAM       |  4500
```

I honestly have no idea why the IDs aren't showing up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the ID column in Courses is not primary key or unique. If not you cannot have duplicates. execute:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE Courses
```

and look at the properties of the ID column

Comment: Oooooh, that definitely sounds like something I would do. I'm heading home right now but I'll definitely check it out when I get home!